# Custom font wont work in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have setup few custom fonts for this page:

http://lynup.com/landing/miamichamber/

But they doesn't appear as they should.
In my root folder, I have
-css
-fonts
index.html

in css folder i have fonts.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';
  src: url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Black';
  src: url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Black.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Medium';
  src: url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf') format('opentype'); 
}

h3{
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Book';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
h4{
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Black';
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
h5{
    font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Medium';
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: The live page does not even try to load the fonts mentioned in the question, just a different .ttf font, and fails with that (404 Not Found).

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer your specific question, you should always include more than one font-fmaily in case the first one fails.

`font-family: 'AvenirLTStd-Medium, Arial, sans-serif';` - for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I just have to write an answer, but it seems to me that your fonts aren't where you're calling them from. The path: ../fonts/fontname.ttf, when I try to navigate to where that would be pointing, it says no file found. The CSS and HTML seem correct to me so they just might be in the wrong place.